# Gulp isn't compiling the scss code into css

Tags: css, sass, compilation, gulp

I am trying to use gulp to convert the scss to css. I am making changes in the scss and nothing is changing in the css. Anyone any ideas on this ? Thanks

My file structure is this :

```
index.html    
app/scss/styles.scss   
app/css/styles.css
```

[file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tanEs.png)

And my gulp file contains this :

```
     var gulp = require('gulp');
      var sass = require('gulp-sass');

  gulp.task('sass', function(){
   return gulp.src('app/scss/styles.scss')
     .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
     .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});

      gulp.task("watch", function() {
     gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", ['sass']);
       });
```

Comment: Is there a styles.css file in the css folder?

Comment: yes I have a styles.css in CSS folder

Comment: Ahh, after your edit - do you have a file watcher to watch for changes to .scss files?

Comment: I have edited my post, I tired using this                     
gulp.task("watch", function() {
gulp.watch("scss/**/*.scss", ['scss']);
});

Comment: Do you have other `.scss` files other than styles.scss that you want to compile? I would recommend making a change to gulp.src in your gulp task named `sass` -- change it from `app/scss/styles.scss` to `app/scss/**/*.scss`. The `**/*` is a way to tell it to check all subdirectories for any files that end in `.scss`"

Comment: For the watch task, the path may need to be updated from `"scss/**/*.scss"` to `"app/scss/**/*.scss"` -- it may be missing the `app` directory at the beginning, so its "watching" the wrong place for file changes

Comment: @miir  .. I have changed it to this                                                                                        
 gulp.task" watch", function() {
gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", ['scss']);
});    but no changes, I have only using the one scss file to test this out

Comment: @kat What gulp commands are you running in the terminal?

Oh, another thing, with `gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", ['scss']);` -- the second param `['scss']` should be renamed to `['sass']`. The items in that array (between the square brackets `[]`) should be the names of other gulp tasks that should run when the watched files are changed. Your other tasks for compling scss is called `'sass'`, so thats the name to use here too

Comment: @miir I have made those changes now, I am running "gulp sass" in the terminal

Comment: @miir I have made those changes now, I am running "gulp sass" in the terminal. I have updated the original code above for these changes, still nothing working yet. I am very new to learning this.

Comment: I have it working now thanks!!, although anytime I want to compile my css I have to run "gulp sass" everytime, would there be a quicker way to make the scss compile by just saving the scss ?

Comment: You need to change to gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", ['sass']); in the "watch" task.  [Note the added app/]

Comment: @kat Yes, instead of running `gulp sass` each time, you can run `gulp watch`. Notice in the gulpfile.js, you have `gulp.task("sass", ... );` and `gulp.task("watch")`. Those are tasks you've defined there, so they are both available to run on the command line with `gulp sass` or `gulp watch` respectively. The watch task is the one that you can run once and it will keep running to detect file changes and each time something changes, it will automatically run `gulp sass` to compile.

Comment: @miir .. I made those changes in the original code above, but gulp task is running in the terminal but it's not making changes to scss and css unless I use gulp sass, any ideas why this might be?                                                                                                    gulp.task("watch", function() {
     gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", ['sass']);
       });

Comment: @kat I am not sure, it looks correct to me... can you explain what steps you are doing and what is your expectation for the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Change the path of the files and dest to the following

```
gulp.task("sass", function () {
  return gulp
    .src("./app/scss/styles.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/css"))

});
```